# Matrix convexity!

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-rank

Given $M\in\Bbb Z_{\geq0,\leq b}^{n\times n}$, if $\mathsf{rank}(M-Q_i)=\mathsf{rank}(Q_i)$ where $i\in\{1,2\}$ with $Q_i\in\Bbb R_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$, then if $\forall {i\in\{1,2\},\quad}\lambda_i\in(0,1):\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_i=1$, is
$$\mathsf{rank}(M-\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_iQ_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^2\mathsf{rank}(M-\lambda_iQ_i)?$$

$$\mathsf{rank}(M-\lambda_iQ_i)=\mathsf{rank}(M-Q_i)?$$

$$\mathsf{rank}(M-\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_iQ_i)=\mathsf{rank}(\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_iQ_i)?$$